# NSLocalizedString only retrieving key in Submodule

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, nslocalizedstring

I am trying to use localisation inside my App. I followed Apple's documentation and various blog posts.

I created the `Localizable.strings` file where I put my English and German translated strings, and replacing all of the hard coded string occurrences with `NSLocalizedString(@"key", nil)` but after running the application in the Simulator only the key value is shown.

I also checked if it's copied to the bundle but everything seems to be fine.

My intention is to add localization to only one submodule inside my workspace which consists of multiple submodules.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is submodule here?

Comment: Sub-projects inside a workspace https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/

Comment: Showing server not found

Comment: Try this link http://pastebin.com/tZVKnY0d it is working for me